# Thread starting during runtime shutdown

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, crashlytics

I get a lot of crashes reported to Crashlytics from my Android app. Here is the crash log, any ideas about the cause?

```
    #0. Crashed: AsyncTask #1: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


Fatal Exception: java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#0. Crashed: AsyncTask #1: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#1. pool-3-thread-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2053)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:806)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#2. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:1197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:4065)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#3. AsyncTask #2
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#4. AsyncTask #3
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zzoJ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.internal.Utility.invokeMethodQuietly(Utility.java:1102)
       at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidIdViaReflection(AttributionIdentifiers.java:117)
       at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidId(AttributionIdentifiers.java:2075)
       at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.getSessionEventsState(AppEventsLogger.java:809)
       at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.access$100(AppEventsLogger.java:147)
       at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger$5.run(AppEventsLogger.java:750)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#5. measurement-1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zzg$zzc.run(Unknown Source)

#6. AsyncTask #4
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#7. Crashlytics Exception Handler1
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:522)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent$13f1f7ff(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:1010)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:23395)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:1278)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#8. Thread-1166
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zzoJ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getInfo(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:106)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getAdvertisingId(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:76)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.getAdvertisingInfo(AdvertisingInfoReflectionStrategy.java:66)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.getAdvertisingInfoFromStrategies(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:118)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.access$000(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:28)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider$1.onRun(AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:70)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#9. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:1197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:4065)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#10. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:970)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1278)
       at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:203)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.awaitSettingsData(Settings.java:142)
       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.doInBackground(Answers.java:388)
       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.doInBackground(Answers.java:25)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground$532ebdd5(InitializationTask.java:1063)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#11. Adjust
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zzoJ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.adjust.sdk.Reflection.invokeMethod(Reflection.java:149)
       at com.adjust.sdk.Reflection.invokeStaticMethod(Reflection.java:134)
       at com.adjust.sdk.Reflection.getAdvertisingInfoObject(Reflection.java:70)
       at com.adjust.sdk.Reflection.getPlayAdId(Reflection.java:21)
       at com.adjust.sdk.DeviceInfo.(DeviceInfo.java:57)
       at com.adjust.sdk.ActivityHandler.initInternal(ActivityHandler.java:378)
       at com.adjust.sdk.ActivityHandler.access$200(ActivityHandler.java:34)
       at com.adjust.sdk.ActivityHandler$SessionHandler.handleMessage(ActivityHandler.java:338)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

#12. AsyncTask #5
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zza.zzoJ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.internal.Utility.invokeMethodQuietly(Utility.java:1102)
       at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidIdViaReflection(AttributionIdentifiers.java:117)
       at com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidId(AttributionIdentifiers.java:2075)
       at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.publishInstallAndWaitForResponse(FacebookSdk.java:451)
       at com.facebook.FacebookSdk$4.run(FacebookSdk.java:439)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#13. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:970)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1278)
       at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:203)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.awaitSettingsData(Settings.java:142)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:349)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:59)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground$532ebdd5(InitializationTask.java:1063)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#14. AsyncTask #1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:421)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:47)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:275)
       at de.yellostrom.incontrol.application.InControl$1.uncaughtException(InControl.java:41)
       at com.helpshift.UncaughtExceptionHandler$1.uncaughtException(UncaughtExceptionHandler.java:46)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)

#15. Queue
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:1197)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:4065)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#16. Answers Events Handler1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1078)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:806)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1036)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: when are you initializing the crashlytics?

Comment: Did you solve the issue ??